# Settings to be changed on domain to control email through separate hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, email

I have a domain name with http://www.lcn.com and I have separate hosting that has cPanel. What settings do I need to change on my domain in LCN so I can send mail through my hosting?

I haven't changed any of the nameservers or dns settings except the mx record.

LCN:
[image]

cPanel:
[image]

This is what I get in the bounce back email:

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

 info@neurosignsurgical.com
   SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<info@neurosignsurgical.com>:
   host mailforward.lcn.com [94.126.40.212]: 550 relay not permitted

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

Return-path: <rob@teamworksdesign.com>
Received: from host-78-145-3-9.as13285.net ([78.145.3.9] helo=[192.168.1.105])
    by clever2.codeworks.org.uk with esmtpsa (TLSv1:AES128-SHA:128)
    (Exim 4.69)
    (envelope-from <rob@teamworksdesign.com>)
    id 1Qz2oo-0006EM-MK
    for info@neurosignsurgical.com; Thu, 01 Sep 2011 09:40:15 +0100
From: Rob Jones <rob@teamworksdesign.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=Apple-Mail-148--595720916
Subject: 
Date: Thu, 1 Sep 2011 09:40:11 +0100
Message-Id: <DD8C8148-A7E8-439A-89AD-F2F2E6EA05D5@teamworksdesign.com>
To: info@neurosignsurgical.com
Mime-Version: 1.0 (Apple Message framework v1084)
X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.1084)
```

Email routing settings:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is create an MX record to point at the mailserver on your hosting. [This page](http://www.lcn.com/support/articles/how-to-get-email-for-your-domain-delivered-to-another-mail-server) from lcn tells you how to do that. You'll need to see the support information for your hosting to see what the mailserver on the hosting is called.

Comment: Thanks, can I just double check with you - I'll update my question with screenshots.

Comment: I've just updated it with screenshots.

Comment: It looks like your hosting isn't set up to receive email at neurosignsurgical.com. I'd contact your hosting support to ask how to receive email.

Comment: We don't really have hosting support as the guy is no longer with us. I've added another screenshot, I think this may be the problem.

Comment: Ok it was the last screenshot added that was the problem, I changed it to local and it now works. Thanks for the help.